# How to see if async method is executing? from another method

Tags: c#

Please look at my code:

```
private void Store()
{
    var books =await Books.DownloadAsync();
    .
    .
}

private void Bookcase()
{
    // here how can I know if Books.DownloadAsync() is executing or not?
}
```

In the above code how can I know if `Books.DownloadAsync() is working?

**Update:** I can't define a property like `IsDownloading = true`, because `Bookcase` and `Store` are in different classes

Comment: Nicolas Butler (also here on SO btw) may have just the right solution for you: http://simplygenius.net/Article/AncillaryAsyncProgress

Comment: Why not? You still can define a public property and access it from the other class!?

Comment: You can define `public static` property/field to access from other class or a normal (non static), if you can pass instance somehow. You can create events `Started` and `Finished`. You can use something what both classes can access (file, static variable in third class, `Mutex`, etc). These are general solutions, but don't ask me if it is good for async programming or not.

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's running? What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The code you've provided wouldn't even compile, as `Store` isn't declared `async`. You haven't really provided enough context as to what's going on here.